# Approving tokens from original contract, how would you do it?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

I need to create a general approval for a transferFrom function for an exchange or general contract if you will. I've tried many ways in solidity to reference the old contract, including using tx.origin to try and get metamask to recognize what I'm doing. While metamask does recognize the interaction with the original contract, it fails to see what token I'm trying to transfer.

```
interface tokenToTransfer {
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external;
}

contract Exchange {
    tokenToTransfer public transferToken;

function approve(address tokenAddress, uint256 approvedeposit) public returns (bool) {
        transferToken = tokenToTransfer(tx.origin);
        transferToken.approve(address(this), approvedeposit);
}
```

So I've gone with a web3 option by loading the contract abi, but this is impractical since I have to load it via etherscan api.

```
await yourcontract.methods.approve("contractabi", 1000000).send({from: accounts[0]});
```

Is there a better way? Am I missing something? Or is the only way to call an approve function only through the native contract due to the restrictions placed by solidity on contract development?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're doing... the end user (the one with the tokens) has to be the one to call `approve`.

Comment: Your current code seems to be trying to call `approve` on `tx.origin`, which doesn't make sense because `tx.origin` is never a contract (so it doesn't have an `approve` method).

Comment: The point is to use a provider such as metamask to initiate an approval on the original contract through a parent contract.